# Testing Values In Excel Before Loading to Table

Tags: c#, excel, load

Using C# I'm loading data from a 10 column Excel spreadsheet (into SQL Server Express) and testing for null values prior to the load. The code I use works fine for non-key fields but when it encounters a null value in a key field I get the following system generated error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'd like the Response.Write to pop up and code execution to halt before the system generates the error. My code is as follows:

```
if ((string)(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString() != null)
{
myVariable = (string)(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
}

else
{
    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Update Aborted... \n \nThe load " +
                                    "process has encountered an incomplete record on row " + rowCount + ". Please " +
                                    "correct your Excel file and reload.');</script>");  

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition should be like this, before converting it into string

```
if (range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2!=null
```

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I'll incorporate the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()
```

Here, if Value2 is null, you'll have NullReferenceException

```
(string)(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString() != null
```

This comparison is pointless, because (string)(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString() cannot be null anyway.

```
(string)(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()
```

Casting to string is pointless, because it's already string.

So I recommend to change it to

```
(range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null
```

Also, operations with ranges are long, so better not to call this code twice and make a variable

```
object value2 = (range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```